# Local policy control in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, security-policy

In `ImageMagick`, is there any way to control policy locally? Something like `~/.imagemagick/policy.xml`.

Update:

```
$ dpkg -l imagemagick
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  imagemagick    8:6.8.9.9-7u amd64        image manipulation programs -- bi

$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick v6 & v7 looks for all files in `~/.config/ImageMagick/` in addition to `/etc`.

This includes `policy.xml`, although I'm not sure what order the policy directives are processed in.

(ImageMagick v6 also used `~/.magick/`, but this is an obsolete location removed from v7.)

To determine what files a program might be looking for, you can use *strace*:

```
strace -e file display test.png |& grep policy.xml
```

Comment: Is there any option for v8? that's the one I'm currently using (8:6.8.9.9-7u), but placing `policy.xml` in that folder doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ImageMagick v8 does not exist as far as I could determine. Even the latest Git master calls itself "version 7.0.8".

Comment: Please, see update in the question.

Comment: That's not v8. That's v6.8.9, Debian package 'epoch' #8.

Comment: According to this post, the only way to use the local policy configuration is to rebuild ImageMagick...  https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29618  , or, to be more precise, you can only control what is not disabled globally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719789/4179803